# Javascript decodeURICompnent() not workign with MySQL encoded UTF-8 String

Tags: javascript, mysql, utf-8, decode

I've tried using `decodeURIComponent()` and `decodeURI()` in javascript on the String *"Ð—Ð°Ð²Ñ‚Ñ€Ð° Ð±Ñ‹Ð»Ð° Ð²Ð¾Ð¹Ð½Ð°"*, which my MySQL database encoded on entering from *"Завтра была война"*

When I enter this String on (some) decoding websites (like https://2cyr.com/decode/ or https://encoder.mattiasgeniar.be/) it decodes just fine, on others it doesn't work (https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-decode) and it also doesn't work with the aforementioned function javascript provides (seen here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G6VG1L4MSBD8).

Why is that the case? Is this a different UTF-8 encoding than what decodeURI[Component]() is for? Can Javascript even decode my specific (already encoded) String or do I have to change the database?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the tools that manage to "decode" this string, it looks like someone took a UTF-8 encoded string and treated the underlying bytes as if they were a Windows-1252 encoded string.

If you receive this from a server (which exact bytes do you receive by the way? Post the HTTP response with the headers) and you have control over the server, you should fix this server-side, instead of trying to work with this in JS.

[decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) works with strings like
`"%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0"`.

Comment: yo sorry for the late answer but thanks, I realized I had to also change the column itself to utf-8 and not just the database

Comment: The %xx format is useful for, as the function name implies, URIs.  It should not, in general, be used for storing in databases.

Answer (score 1):

`Ð—Ð°Ð²Ñ‚Ñ€Ð° Ð±Ñ‹Ð»Ð° Ð²Ð¾Ð¹Ð½Ð°` is Mojibake for `Завтра была война`.  That means that some step in the processing got confused between latin1 and utf8.  The proper hex for the Cyrillic is (I added spaces)

```
D097 D0B0 D0B2 D182 D180 D0B0 20 D0B1 D18B D0BB D0B0 20 D0B2 D0BE D0B9 D0BD D0B0
```

That is what you *should* see with `SELECT HEX(col) ..` from MySQL.

You should probably not use any "decode" functions.

See [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for likely causes of Mojibake.